# How to make this column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames,
df1:

```
Col1
25
25
26
27
27
28
```

and df2:

```
Col1
25    
25
25
26
27
27
```

I am trying to make a column, `df1$Col2` in which it contains 1 if its respective value in `df1$Col1` appears in `df2$Col1` a different number of times than it appears in `df1$Col1`. Hence, it would look like this:

df1:

```
Col1 Col2
25   1
25   1
26   0
27   0
27   0
28   0
```

Thanks!

Comment: But `Col1[5]` (27) is in Col1 and Col2 at the same row. Is ok your desired output?

Comment: There are 2 27s in `df1` and in `df2`. However there are 2 25s in `df1` and 3 25s in `df2`. Hence, I want to flag all of the 25s in `df1`

Comment: How Col1[6] 28 , still 0 ?

Comment: @Wen, sorry I could have made that a little bit more clear. If there's a new value, I'd prefer it's `Col2` value to just be `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(Col1) %>%
  mutate(n1 = n()) %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>% group_by(Col1) %>% summarize(n2 = n())
  )
  mutate(Col2 = as.numeric(n1 != n2))
```

There will be a couple extra columns at the end, but you can drop them if you want.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to import dplyr tho?

Comment: Yes. Yes you would. You could also do this pretty simply with `data.table`.